# Wildfly8.2 service no starting correctly on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, wildfly8

I am running wildfly on ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS, when I try and start the service I get the following:

```
service wildfly start
* Starting WildFly Application Server wildfly
   ...done.
* WildFly Application Server hasn't started within the timeout allowed
* please review file "/var/log/wildfly/console.log" to see the status of the service
```

The script is grepping the log file

`grep 'JBAS015874:' "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" > /dev/null`

The string "JBAS015874:" never gets logged. The last line the server logs is:

`INFO  [ra] HornetQ resource adaptor started [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-1)`

However if I point lynx to localhost:8080 I do see the wildfly welcome page.

Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel like a fool.

The issue was logging, a while back I had reduced the logging on startup.

I have to add the following log configuration:

```
<logger category="org.jboss.as">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

The string `JBAS015874:` is now being logged on start up and the service script is not complaining.

As an aside I think that there should be a better way for the service to establish whether wildfly has started.